# Subir una imagen a Spring -mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, fileupload

Estoy tratando de subir una imagen con `Spring-mvc` utilziando para ello `Commons FileUpload` estoy siguiendo lo siguiente http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload 
llamo a fileUpload en mi controlador y entra pero no sube la imagen.
Los pasos que he seguido son:
Añadir la dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

He establecido el MultipartConfigElement añadiendo la ubicación y el tamaño máximo a lo que ya tenia

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private String TMP_FOLDER = "C:/Users/SilviaGM/Desktop/git tfg"; 
private int MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 



public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

            // Dispatcher Servlet
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
                    new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/");

            dispatcher.setInitParameter("contextClass", appContext.getClass().getName());

            servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

            // UTF8 Charactor Filter.
            FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

            fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
            fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
            fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");  


            //Nuevo para subir la imagen
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(
                    new GenericWebApplicationContext()));

                  appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

                  MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(TMP_FOLDER, 
                    MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE * 2, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE / 2);

                  appServlet.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);
        }
    }
```

He añadido el **@Bean**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // Static Resource Config 
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

Y por último he añadido el método al controlador:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("file", file);
     System.out.println("Estoy aqui"); //Me muestra el valor por lo que es llamado el metodo.
    return "fileUploadView";
}
```

> Mi problema es que la imagen no se sube al directorio: "C:/Users/SilviaGM/Desktop/git tfg"; y no encuentro el problema o si me falta algo en la configuración

Comment: Recomendaría que el directorio tuviera un nombre sin espacios

Comment: Tenes permisos de escritura en dicho directorio?

Comment: @Silvia has probado con la ruta doble contra diagonal \\ ??

Comment: Ya probe en un directorio sin espacios, con ruta con \\ y nada, sigue todo igual, en cuanto a los permisos si tengo de escritura ya que mi programa crea archivos en el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola en cuanto a la parte de la configuración:

```
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(TMP_FOLDER, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE * 2, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE / 2);
```

El último parámetro indica cuando se van a persistir automáticamente los archivos en la ubicación indicada, por lo tanto tienes varias situaciones entre estas que tu archivo no está alcanzando el tamaño mínimo para ser persistido automáticamente

De pretender hacer el proceso manualmente, lo que te queda sería validar que no esté vacío y por último persistirlo de la manera que lo prefieras, sea en el disco duro, en una db etc...

Para este caso voy a hacerlo en el disco duro ya que veo que es lo que estás buscando, y utilizaré una librería que me facilitará el proceso pero tu puedes hacerlo con cualquier otro método. La librería que utilizaré se llama: **org.apache.commons.io**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Ahora en tu controlador:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, ModelMap 
modelMap) {
    //donde guardarás tu archivo, asegurate de que tengas permisos de escritura
    String pathFinal = "C:/archivosSubidos";
    //validación básica
    if(!multipartFile.isEmpty()){
      //creo un nuevo archivo
      File file = new File(pathFinal);
      FileUtils.touch(file);
      //transfiero el archivo multipart al disco.
      multipartFile.transferTo(file);
    }
    return "fileUploadView";
}
```

Aún no he podido probar mi código, pero como te das cuenta, se debe decidir que vas a hacer con el archivo.

Saludos.

Comment: No quiero editar mas mi respuesta, pero la configuración de subida de archivos también depende del tipo de servlet, por lo tanto si tienes un servlet 3.0, para este caso no es necesario el `@Bean CommonsMultipartResolver`

Comment: Muchas gracias, se me olvido cerrar la pregunta, pero sí, mi problema es que no tenia bien el controlador porque no indicaba que hacer con el archivo